# Spring boot enable Https : SSL Keystore Error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, keystore, jks

I am trying to enable https in my spring boot application but getting 'Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect' error. Following are the below configuration i have in my application properties file.

```
server.port=8083
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=C:\\Users\\abc.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=C:\\Users\\password.txt

However when i am using TomcatServletWebServerFactory to redirect http to https with the below configuration in application properties it works fine without any issue. application starts on http 8081 and https 8083 ports.

server.port=8083
http.server.port= 8081
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.key-store=C:\\Users\\abc.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password=C:\\Users\\password.txt


    

I am not able to find root cause and resolve the issue. Please help me to find out what i am doing wrong. 

**Spring boot : 2.3.2.RELEASE
tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37
jdk1.8.0_111**
```

Below is the error.

```
[AsyncReporter{org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.zipkin2.sender.RestTemplateSender@355ce6a6}] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: standardService.connector.startFailed 
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect 
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect 
Caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing key password.

`server.ssl.key-password=yourpasswordhere`